# "Can't call yield in a noYieldsAllowed block!" error on server when client connects

Tags: meteor

I'm using external mongo instance at mongohq, so I have

```
MONGO_URL=mongodb://heroku:censored@alex.mongohq.com:10025/appCensored
```

in in my environment. I'm using this mongo instance in "read-only" mode, using my meteor app as monitoring application. _id's in all collections are not meteor uuids.

When I start meteor and connect a client to localhost:3000, I got the following obscure error message on server:

`Internal exception while processing message { msg: 'sub',
  id: '9e11edd5-b8a5-4a67-86de-a3270ef3601f',
  name: 'content',
  params: [ 'ORG-4d9d4981-55d8-44ee-9025-32c41be679ca' ] } Error: Can't call yield in a noYieldsAllowed block!
    at Function.Meteor._noYieldsAllowed.Fiber.yield (app/packages/meteor/fiber_helpers.js:13:11)
    at Function.wait (/usr/local/meteor/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:111:14)
    at Object.Future.wait (/usr/local/meteor/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:321:10)
    at _Mongo._createSynchronousCursor (app/packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js:369:23)
    at _Mongo._observe (app/packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js:493:14)
    at Object.Meteor._noYieldsAllowed (app/packages/meteor/fiber_helpers.js:17:12)
    at _Mongo._observe (app/packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js:485:10)
    at Cursor._observeUnordered (app/packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js:344:22)
    at Cursor._publishCursor (app/packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js:305:28)
    at sub._runHandler (app/packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:378:13)`

and I got no documents in 'content' collection on the client. When I refresh browser and reconnect client to server, everything goes smoothly and I got documents in 'content'. Looks like that something is wrong with subscription to 'content' collection. Publish and subscribe code for this collection is below:

```
server.coffee
-------------
Content = new Meteor.Collection 'content'

Meteor.publish 'content', (org) ->
    Content.find { recipientUid: org }

client.coffee
-------------
Content = new Meteor.Collection 'content'

Meteor.autosubscribe ->
    uid = Session.get 'testUserUid'
    if uid
        Meteor.subscribe 'content', uid

Template.main.top_content = ->
    # observe won't work with limited collections, use workaround
    top = Content.find({}, { sort: { total: -1 } }).fetch()
    top.slice 0, 10
```

What I do wrong?

Comment: There is a change in the 0.7.1 -> 0.7.1.2 of meteor that trips a similar error message.  Check out this thread for more details:
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1868

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug introduced in 0.5.1. I've just released Meteor 0.5.2 which should fix it (in fact, it makes no changes other than fixing this issue). Try upgrading with `meteor update` and let me know if this does not fix your issue!

Comment: There is a change in the 0.7.1 -> 0.7.1.2 of meteor that trips a similar error message. Check out this thread for more details: github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1868

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error, but with observer. As I found out later that this error happens than there is no connection to the database.
Due to async nature of meteor. It does not wait till the connection to the database is fully established and starts to execute other code and accept connections.

Try to place your subscription code into Meteor.startup(...) on the client side like this.

```
initSubscripions = ->
  uid = Session.get 'testUserUid'
  Meteor.subscribe 'content', uid if uid


Meteor.startUp ->
  initSubscripions
```